# Pass application.conf file at deploy time in Docker setup built using jar

Tags: scala, docker, sbt

My requirement is to pass the `application.conf` file for Play framework based Scala application at deploy time in a Docker setup on Kubernetes, in order to support values passed using `secrets`. However, the constraint I have is I use the application's fat-jar as entrypoint in the Dockerfile:

```
...
EXPOSE 9000
ENTRYPOINT java -jar myapp.jar
```

I want to build the fat-jar with reference to that `application.conf` which will be passed at deploy time (using secrets), with SBT command, something like:

```
sbt -Dconfig.file="/opt/myorg/myapp/application.conf" clean publish
```

But this would fail as the file would only be available at deploy time. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your deploy so that container takes this file from somewhere or change the approach of getting the needed properties.
For example:

- you can execute ssh/scp command that will copy the file into the container and support this by k8s because by default it will shuffle/recreate containers in the cluster (this is an awful solution, but you can get the idea from it)
- you can attach the external volume with this file to the container and then pass the path to the java process. Something like that should work `ENTRYPOINT java -jar myapp.jar -Dconfig.file="/opt/myorg/myapp/application.conf"`.
- add config as a file to the jar at build time (but as I understood build time is not the case)
- change how your app gets the properties so that it can get them from the env variables, and define env during the deploy process

I'm not a k8s user, so I can't tell you the exact way of doing this. But I hope some of that can help you.

Comment: Note that if using Lightbend config, one can write a `.conf` file such that it will pull overrides from env variables.

Comment: Artem: For your suggestion with bullets: <1.> Im already able to copy the secrets based file into the container, so this isn't an issue. <2.> Adding `-Dconfig.file` to `java -jar` command wont work. <3.> yes, adding at build time isn't an option for me. <4.> Passing secret information in env variables isnt the best secure solution. So i'm trying the option of reading the secrets file in a separate Guice Module file for the required parameters. Thanks for your response. Will mark it accepted once I am able to proceed with point 4.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by using option #2 suggested. A point to note would be to use the `-Dconfig.file=""` before the `-jar` attribute. Using it after will throw errors. This works:  `ENTRYPOINT java -Dconfig.file="/opt/myorg/myapp/application.conf" -jar myapp.jar`